Fantasy book where the main character, an archer or a hunter, goes home to find his village burned by crown soldiers
ok so the beginning of the book started with an archer or hunter going back home when he also finds his friend, they walk home together on the way they hide because they see soldiers from the crown walking their way. when they go home they find their village burned to the ground. and old man who was the wanderer is also there. a few book later they are being chases and so they hide in an ancient empires temple which is guarded by three ghost sisters

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  How many books were there?  Do you remember the cover art?

Could be Conan the Barbarian, though IIRC he's a kid. It's a pretty common trope in fantasy anyway.
